# C: member to drive up structure size up to a value

Tags: c, c11

I have a structure that looks like this:

```
struct myStructure
{
    int index1;
    int index2;
    void *buffer;
    char fillData[];
};
```

I want to make the fillData member as big as it needs to make the structure an arbitrary size (512 bytes). I know I can calculate by hand and write that down but,to make this easily extensible in the future, I want it to scale up or down if needed automatically. Is there a way to achieve this automatic behaviour only using the preprocessor?

Comment: using gcc extension offsetof

Comment: Do you need strictly ISO C, or are you able to use compiler extensions? If so, what compiler are you using?

Comment: I use gcc with the std set to gnu11

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`offsetof` cannot be used, because it needs the fully definition of the `struct` to work: https://godbolt.org/z/brEhThhe7

But you can put everything before the `fillData` into a `struct` and use `sizeof` on it:

```
struct myStructure
{
    struct inner {
        int index1;
        int index2;
        void *buffer;
    } inner;
    char fillData[WHOLE_SIZE - sizeof(struct inner)];
};
```

https://godbolt.org/z/zacxG1xrh

Using `sizeof` on all members might not work because of padding.

Comment: This fails in Apple Clang 11.0.0: “error: offsetof of incomplete type 'struct myStructure'”.

Comment: @EricPostpischil You are right, I had a typo in the first version. `offsetof` cannot be used at all, even gcc rejects it. I edited my answer, only the way over the inner struct works for me.

Comment: In theory the compiler is free to insert padding between `inner` and the `char` array, which does not count as part of the size of `inner`. In practice, doing so doesn't make any sense so it's unlikely to happen in the real world.